# Modeling this stochastic process

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, mathematical-modeling, markov-process

I'd like to model a process where:

- at time $t = 0$, there is one organism with characteristics $X_1$. It chooses another organism. This organism's characteristics $X_2$ are drawn from a distribution $F$, and the expected value of the distribution is $X_1$.
- at time $t = 1$, these two organisms together select a third individual from a distribution $F$, and the expected value of the distribution is the mean of organism 1 and 2's characteristics, $\frac{X_1 + X_2}{2}$.
- ...
- at time $t$, the existing $t+1$ organisms, who have characteristics $X_1,..,X_{t+1}$, respectively, choose a $(t+2)$th individual from a distribution $F$, and the expected value of the distribution is the mean of existing organism's characteristics, $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{t+1} X_i}{t+1}$.

For simplicity we can say $F$ is the normal distribution.

Does this resemble any named stochastic process?

Comment: I assume you mean $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{t+1} X_i}{t+1}$ instead of $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{t+1} X_i}{2}$, right?

Comment: Conditional normals are still normal, so that simplifies the problem. Let $Z_1,Z_2,...$ be iid $N(0,1)$, then you'd get that $X_1=Z_1$, then $X_2=Z_1+Z_2$, then $X_3=\frac{X_1+X_2}{2}+Z_3=\frac{1}{2}Z_2+Z_1+Z_3$, then $X_4 = \frac{X_1+X_2+X_3}{3}+Z_4 = Z_1 + \frac{1}{2}Z_2 +\frac{1}{3}Z_3+Z_4$, and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easier to look at your process in terms of the means $Y_t = \frac1{t+1}\sum_{i=1}^{t+1} X_i$.  Then $Y_{t+1} = Y_t + \frac1{t+2}W_{t+1}$, where the random variables $W_t$ are i.i.d. with a zero mean.

In particular, this implies that the process $(Y_0, Y_1, Y_2, \dots)$ is a [martingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)).  In particular, if the distribution of the increments $W_t$ (i.e. your $F$ distribution) is Gaussian, then the only difference between your process and an unbiased [Gaussian random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#Gaussian_random_walk) is the $\frac1{t+2}$ scaling of the increments, which should lead to some kind of [anomalous diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_diffusion).

Specifically, let the variance of the unscaled increments $W_t$ be $\sigma^2$.  Then $Y_t$ has the variance $$\sigma_t^2 = \sum_{\tau=1}^{t+1} \frac{\sigma^2}{\tau^2} = \sigma^2 \sum_{\tau=1}^{t+1} \frac1{\tau^2} = H^{(2)}_{t+1} \sigma^2,$$ where $H^{(2)}_n$ is the $n$-th [generalized harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers) with exponent 2.  In particular, as $t$ increases, the variance of $Y_t$ converges to the limit $$\lim_{t \to \infty} \sigma^2_t = \frac{\pi^2}6 \sigma^2.$$  This implies that the means $Y_t$ will also [converge in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables) to some limiting distribution with finite variance (assuming that $\sigma^2$ is finite to begin with).  In particular, if the increments $W_t$ are Gaussian, then $Y_t$ will also have a Gaussian distribution, and thus (since a Gaussian distribution is uniquely defined by its mean and variance), the distribution of $Y_t$ will converge to $\mathcal N(0, \frac{\pi^2}6 \sigma^2)$.